# communication of several SPI slaves per matrix LED 8x8 MAX7219

Tags: raspbian

cordial greeting, I find myself working with four independent arrays 8X8 controlled by the MAX7219 by SPI making use of the library MAX7219 driver and the library luma.led_matrix. The inconvenience that I find is that I only have CE0 and CE1 in the communication by SPI I have treated to establish communication for free GPIO pins but it has not been possible. Could I configure this correctly? Below I indicate an example of what I have tried.

```
import max7219.led as led
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


#configuracion de pines GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7, True)


device = led.matrix(cascaded = 1)
GPIO.output(7, False)
device.letter(0,ord('B'))
GPIO.output(7, True)
```

Comment: Could you explain what you expected to get, and what you got instead? Does "inconvenience" mean that the communication works, but not with the pins you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it hard to follow your post; probably a translation problem.

From what I gather you want to use more than 2 SPI channels.
Apart from SPI0 you can also activate SPI1 with 1 to 3 chip selects.

For 2 more channels you can add this line to /boot/config.txt

```
dtoverlay=spi1-2cs
```

Details are available in /boot/overlays/README. An excerpt for SPI1:

```
Name:   spi1-2cs
Info:   Enables spi1 with two chip select (CS) lines and associated spidev
        dev nodes. The gpio pin numbers for the CS lines and spidev device node
        creation are configurable.
        N.B.: spi1 is only accessible on devices with a 40pin header, eg:
              A+, B+, Zero and PI2 B; as well as the Compute Module.
Load:   dtoverlay=spi1-2cs,<param>=<val>
Params: cs0_pin                 GPIO pin for CS0 (default 18 - BCM SPI1_CE0).
        cs1_pin                 GPIO pin for CS1 (default 17 - BCM SPI1_CE1).
        cs0_spidev              Set to 'disabled' to stop the creation of a
                                userspace device node /dev/spidev1.0 (default
                                is 'okay' or enabled).
        cs1_spidev              Set to 'disabled' to stop the creation of a
                                userspace device node /dev/spidev1.1 (default
                                is 'okay' or enabled).
```

As you can see it is possible to change the chip select pins.

NB: pin numbers use the Broadcom (BCM) scheme! see https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi)

BTW: I think it may also be possible to connect all the led matrices to a single SPI channel and still address them individually

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk for your prompt response. What I need is the last thing you comment from a SPI0 channel to connect more than two slaves and address them individually. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can use 2 slaves on SPI0 and 2 on SPI1. `What I need is the last thing you comment from a SPI0 channel to connect more than two slaves and address them individually.` That's not what I'm saying; please re-read carefully: I think you could do it with a single chip select. Don't have the time to hunt it down, though.